# Why can't I put my functions in another class?

Tags: java

I created a new class called "Tools" inside my "com.example.hello" workspace.

Tools.java:

```
public class Tools {
    public static String getSource (String theurl) {
        URL u;
        InputStream is = null;
        DataInputStream dis;
        String s;
        String ss = "";
        try {
           u = new URL(theurl);
           is = u.openStream();         // throws an IOException
           dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
           while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
              ss = ss +  s;
           }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } finally {
           try {
              is.close();
              return ss;
           } catch (IOException ioe) {
           }
        } 
        return ss;
     }         
}
```

From that exact namespace (com.example.hello), there is a .java file in there...and I want to use getSource.

I tried `import com.example.hello.Tools.*`

But for some reason, I can't use getSource?

I just want to be able to call "getSource" from my other classes that are in the same folder.

Comment: "But for some reason, I can't use getSource?"  I expect the compilation error message tells you why ... but you didn't include that in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
import static com.example.hello.Tools.*;
```

to use `getSource()` without writing `Tools.getSource()`. Of course if you want to write `Tools.getSource()` just use a standard `import`:

```
import com.example.hello.Tools;
```

Comment: But then when there is a private class NESTED in that class, I can't use the Tools anymore?

Comment: @alex: do you mean that private nested class can't use Tools or external classes can't because there is a private nested class? Either way, you can use Tools in both scenarios. The Tools class isn't inatantiated when you call static methods.

Comment: Yes. I have private class... inside this original big class. And inside that private class there is a method that calls getSource(). But it's undefined or something.

Comment: @alex: Perhaps you should post a second question about that. Or maybe post a code snippet in this one because I have no issues calling a static method from an outer class inside an inner class (static or not, private or not) so I'm not sure what issue you're having.

Comment: You don't need to do `import com.example.hello.Tools;` in the second case. It is in the same package.

Answer (score 4):

```
import static com.example.hello.Tools.*;
```

Here is a pointer to [static import](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

**EDIT** : You can also call as `Tools.getSource()`. Since `Tools` is in the same package you don't need to import it.

Comment: But then when there is a private class NESTED in that class, I can't use the Tools anymore?

Comment: What?  You can never use a private inner class outside of its enclosing class.  That's the whole point of declaring it private!

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to add the following?  (Asking because I don't see it in your example.)

```
package com.example.hello;
```

It's not enough to place the file in the proper folder structure;  you have to provide a package declaration at the top of the file.