# Why can't I call this function in Java?

Tags: java

```
import static com.example.hello.Tools.*;
public class MAINCLASS{
   public void run(){
      runtools(); // this works
   }
   private class People{
      public void runpeople(){
          runtools(); // this does not work.
      }
   } 
}
```

Inside Tools...

Edit: When I roll over runtools() in People.runpeople()...I get this:

**The method runtools() is undefined for the type MAINCLASS.People**

```
public class Tools {
    public void runtools() {
     ....
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't work?  Compiler error, runtime exception, etc?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the 'static' bit of the import statement?

Comment: More like how _does_ it work? It does not compile as written.

Comment: .. so no-one else has noticed that he's asked the same question twice, and got the same answer twice, and accepted the same answer twice? Rep-whoring much?

Comment: @TomatoSandwich it is not the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare `Tools#runtools()` `static` to be able to `import static` it.

```
public class Tools {
    public static void runtools() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Either that, or instantiate `Tools` and then call `runtools()` on it.

```
new Tools().runtools();
```

Answer (score 1):

In reference to another question you asked recently related to this same class and it's issues: [Why can't I put my functions in another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269886/why-cant-i-put-my-functions-in-another-class/2269900#2269900)

Does taking cletus' suggestion of removing the 'static' from the import call fix this issue as well? The 'static' bit is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `runtools()` should not work in either of those two cases, since runtools is not a static method - it needs an instance of the `Tools` object to be invoked on.

Answer (score 1):

That code shouldn't work (at all) as you posted it because you only import static members of Tools, and runtools() is an instance method. If you were to make runtools() static, then both invocations of runtools() should work because it is in scope in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This does not compile. You cannot import a package, with the static keyword. The import needs to be a specific method.

So you need to write something like this to make it compile, and work:

```
import static com.example.hello.Tools.someMethod;
```

Also, the method you're importing needs to be static.

This makes you call a static method like it was declared in the scope of this class:

```
someMethod();
```